# What is the relationship between Marshallian demand and Two-Stage Least Squares Estimation Procedure

Tags: microeconomics, econometrics, consumer-theory

I was reading Varian, and he gives an example of how to find the quantities demanded using a CobbDouglas utility function with observable data, and a question arose: what is the relationship between this approach and simply doing a [two-stage regression](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/195495_d47be7c818424a3c9bfa5452dd17c6c6.html) for price and demand?

Does the Marshallian demand and the regression approach answer different questions?
Does one solve a problem that the other cannot solve?

Comment: What is Varian's example of finding a demand function?

Comment: Also, Varian has several books and scores of papers, which one were you reading?

Comment: Estimating the relationship between quantity and price in the demand curve is challenging. The reason is you only observe equilibrium $(price_{t}, quantity_t)$. However such pairs do not necessarily represent movement up and down the demand curve (at different supply conditions) but also include changes in demand conditions. In  "the tariff on animal and vegetable oils" Phillip Wright (1928) suggested using instrumental variables hence inventing the 2SLS.  The Marshellian demand is an economic theoretical entity describing the nature of demand, 2SLS is a method to estimate this demand.